# jQuery - select invisible text overlaid on image, ala GMail PDF viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm overlaying invisible text on top of an image. Is there a jQuery plugin (or similar) that will allow users to select an area on the image (which also selects the overlaid text) and be able to copy the content.

Right now, I have placed each character in its own `<span />` tag. Problem is when user selects, it sometimes select all the overlaid text (unless user is extremely precise with his/her mouse), sometimes the image itself becomes selected, etc.

A solution similar to GMail's PDF viewer would be nice. Suggestions?

Comment: "invisible" meaning? is it display none, forecolor=backcolor, visible false? There is a jquery image crop plugin which lets you select an area on an image, but the text part you'll have to code a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google seems to know from a pdf where the various `x,y` text offsets are in the file. When you select a bunch of lines, it places a set of absolutely positioned "selection" divs over the image where the "text" is (they have class `highlight-pane`). When you select text, it fills in a `#selection-content` textarea with the contents of what you have selected, and selects the text in it (try using `window.getSelection().anchorNode` in Chrome, e.g.). Besides those selection overlays, there is just an image `.page-image`. I bet they actually use window to capture all the mouse gestures they care about (I assume `mousedown` and `mouseup`). ([Here's an example pdf document](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://labs.google.com/papers/bigtable-osdi06.pdf))

If you're absolute-positioning the elements, you could detect `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup`, figure out the span elements mouse is over (or nearest to), and fill in a textarea with the contents of all content between those two elements. If you want to just use word-granularity, I doubt anyone would complain (surround each word with a span, rather than each letter).

**Edit**: I got kinda curious last night and coded up a *really* naive version. It only does `mousedown` and `mouseup`, and it doesn't work in IE (I don't feel like debugging it :)

[Check it out on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PmjTj/)

Features you might want to add:

1. Some better way of checking for position-based matches; I just do whether it's included in the box.
2. Dynamic updating on `mousemove`
3. Line-based rather than span-based
4. You could still do selecting by background color, but depending on how your elements are arranged it might not look very good. Also would need to support transparency.

Comment: @hookd Thanks! It kinda hooked me, at least for the quick proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a simple example using my answer to your previous question: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/83W7X/2/embedded/result**

```
var selected = [];

function drawSelection(){
    if(selected.length){
        selected.sort(function(a, b){
            if(a.sourceIndex){
                return a.sourceIndex - b.sourceIndex;
            } else if(a.compareDocumentPosition){
                if(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) == Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING){
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        });
        var range = rangy.createRange(),
            sel = rangy.getSelection();

        range.setStart(selected[0].children[0], 0);
        range.setEnd(selected[selected.length - 1].children[0], 1);
        sel.setSingleRange(range);
    }
}

$('ul').selectable({
    delay: 100,
    selecting: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.selecting.getAttribute('class').indexOf('wrapper') !== -1 && $.inArray(ui.selecting, selected) === -1) {
            selected.push(ui.selecting);
            drawSelection();
        }
    },
    unselecting: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.unselecting.getAttribute('class').indexOf('wrapper') !== -1 && $.inArray(ui.unselecting, selected) > -1){
            selected.splice($.inArray(ui.unselecting, selected), 1);
            drawSelection();
        }
    }
});
```

It mixes jQuery UI's Selectable with Tim Down's excellent Rangy library to create something similar to what you asked for. I think. What you asked for wasn't exactly clear.

The code keeps an array of currently selected `li` elements. The second part of the code adds in the relevant event handlers and options. The `drawSelection` function is called every time an element is selected or deselected. The function first sorts all elements by their position in the DOM, then proceeds to draw a selection from the first selected `li` to the last.

The code, like [theazureshadow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130412/jquery-select-invisible-text-overlaid-on-image-ala-gmail-pdf-viewer/4131438#4131438), is proof-of-concept only, since I'm abstracting what really should be the simple task of selecting the `li`s to the rather heavy Rangy library. It also does not perform very well and could do with some refactoring.